How to create mod for snapshot 24w14a
I`m trying to create simple mod on newest snapshot 24w14a, but when I starting client client then I`m getting error
Mod 'untitled1' (untitled1) 1.0-SNAPSHOT requires version 24w14a of 'Minecraft' (minecraft), but only the wrong version is present: 1.20.5-alpha.24.14.a!
I just created new project using Minecraft plugin in IDEA, and made no changes, but it not works, anyone have ideas, what to do?
I have already installed java 21, as it needed
Updated fabric loom to newer version and gradle to 8.6
Client error screenshot

The IntelliJ generated fabric projects for snapshots are strange like that.
You need to edit fabric.mod.jsons's depends block to change it to the requested version.
For your use case:
"depends": {
    "fabricloader": ">=0.15.9",
    "fabric": "*",
    "minecraft": ">=1.20.5-alpha.24.14.a",
    "java": ">=21"
}

This is set to accept 24w14a or higher.
